# how to import rigging and bones from Poser11 to 3Ds Max

Tags: graphics, 3dsmax, 3d-modelling, 3d-model, 3ds

Im working and animating models on 3Ds max, but i need to import for example a horse to the poser to do more animating on characters face. please help me do that if everybody knows how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Poser is very restricted when it goes for importing and exporting rigged and animated objects. The best (and probably the only) way to do that is by using an .**FBX** format with rigging, which is sadly available only for **Poser Pro Game Dev** variety of the app, and then, importing into 3ds Max can produce some weird results. In most cases the rigging will be slightly off and the bones will be very tiny / weird, but you can try and give it a shot. That's the only way to do it without re-rigging the whole thing. Wonder how DAZ Studio export rigged FBX files...